# lazy binding click event on elements not on dom

Tags: javascript

There are few elements on our DOM which are loaded as a response to a webservice.
I want to bind click event on them. 
I do not have any control on webservice call, as it is done by a framework I am not intending to modify.

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function)
```

This would have helped me but the jquery version that is being used is older.
Is there an alternative or native javascript solution to this?

Comment: How can you identify these elements?

Comment: Which version of jQuery? If >= 1.4.2 you can use `.delegate()` instead of `.on()`.

Comment: There is a specific class associated  with these elements

Comment: This code will do `$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );`

Comment: @nnnnnn As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the `.on()` method.

Comment: @Lucky - yes, I know. The OP mentioned needing an alternative to `.on()` that would work with an older version, hence my suggestion. I hoped to prompt them to read the doco...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One of the hot methodologies in the JavaScript world is event delegation, and for good reason.  Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent. Refer this: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ", e.target.id.replace("post-"), " was clicked!");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Amit, I may have missed something. Will you mind sharing that ? I do have a option of **edit** to correct it! I just tried to guide him..

Comment: What I meant in my comment is that after a simple question, OP explained that the elements can be identified by a specific CSS class, not a nodeName (and not `<li>` which is as random as any other criteria). So, you're answer is technically correct, but ignores the details of what OP needs. Additionally, it might be possible to offer a better solution once all details are known (not applicable here though). My comment is to "criticize" your decision to answer before you know the details.

Comment: @Amit, You are right! But I basically **focused** on *native javascript solution* mentioned in the question! Moreover, Details provided in comments were not provided in the question hence I could not consider them!